# How to get more information about cv::Stitcher failing

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, homography

I have two cameras that are looking overhead at a square object, and I'd like to take the two images and combine them to get one image that is (approximately) representative of the overall area.

The views from my two cameras look like so:

[image: Two camera images.]

The left edge of the left image should stitch with the right edge of the right image, with the dotted black line being the point where they overlap.

My first attempt is to stitch the images together using the technique in this tutorial:

http://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/11/22/panorama-image-stitching-in-opencv/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace cv;

void readme();

/** @function main */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
 if( argc != 3 )
 { readme(); return -1; }

// Load the images
 Mat image1= imread( argv[2] );
 Mat image2= imread( argv[1] );
 Mat gray_image1;
 Mat gray_image2;
 // Convert to Grayscale
 cvtColor( image1, gray_image1, CV_RGB2GRAY );
 cvtColor( image2, gray_image2, CV_RGB2GRAY );

imshow("first image",image2);
 imshow("second image",image1);

if( !gray_image1.data || !gray_image2.data )
 { std::cout<< " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1; }

//-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
 int minHessian = 400;

SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );

std::vector< KeyPoint > keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;

detector.detect( gray_image1, keypoints_object );
 detector.detect( gray_image2, keypoints_scene );

//-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
 SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;

extractor.compute( gray_image1, keypoints_object, descriptors_object );
 extractor.compute( gray_image2, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene );

//-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
 FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
 std::vector< DMatch > matches;
 matcher.match( descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches );

double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

//-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
 for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
 { double dist = matches[i].distance;
 if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
 if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
 }

printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist );
 printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist );

//-- Use only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
 std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
 { if( matches[i].distance < 3*min_dist )
 { good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); }
 }
 std::vector< Point2f > obj;
 std::vector< Point2f > scene;

for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
 {
 //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
 obj.push_back( keypoints_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
 scene.push_back( keypoints_scene[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
 }

// Find the Homography Matrix
 Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );
 // Use the Homography Matrix to warp the images
 cv::Mat result;
 warpPerspective(image1,result,H,cv::Size(image1.cols+image2.cols,image1.rows));
 cv::Mat half(result,cv::Rect(0,0,image2.cols,image2.rows));
 image2.copyTo(half);
 imshow( "Result", result );

 waitKey(0);
 return 0;
 }

/** @function readme */
 void readme()
 { std::cout << " Usage: Panorama < img1 > < img2 >" << std::endl; }
```

Unfortunately, this fails (consistently) with the error:

`Debug Assertion Failed! Program: ....\VC\include\xmemory0 Line 106 
Expression "(_Ptr_user & (_BIG_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT -1)) == 0" && 0`

The call stack indicates that this happens during the call to `std::_Deallocate<cv::KeyPoint>` -- presumably when the keypoints vectors are deallocated.

Needless to say, the image stitching fails.

I've tried using the `cv::Stitcher` class, but I get the same error.

How can I attempt to stitch images together and get information about how or why this is failing?

Comment: Unrelated to the direct question, but you should note that your tutorial assumes *one camera location taking two photos*.  You may not like the results of attempting to stitch photos taken from different locations.

Comment: Oh!  I didn't realize that was a requirement.  Is there a way to identify features in a pair of images (even manually) and then get an approximate stitch of the two images?

Comment: I tried this code with these test images, and I get the same error in the destructor for `cv::DMatch`  --  https://imgur.com/a/u34NJ

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `cv::Stitcher` such a way like below, it is the simplest way to warp images to each other:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/stitching/stitcher.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cv::Mat img1 = cv::imread("image1.jpg");
    cv::Mat img2 = cv::imread("image2.jpg");

    if (img1.empty() || img2.empty())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    std::vector<cv::Mat> imgs;
    imgs.push_back(img1);
    imgs.push_back(img2);
    // push more images here ...

    cv::Mat panoramic;
    cv::Stitcher stitcher = cv::Stitcher::createDefault(true);
    stitcher.stitch(imgs, panoramic);

    cv::imshow("Result", panoramic);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives me the same error -- it crashes while trying to deallocate the vectors inside of the Stitcher class :(

Comment: Which OpenCV version do you use for testing? Don't you mix debug/release dll's?

Comment: I'm using OpenCv 2.4.11 with Visual Studio 2015.  I'm not mixing .dlls, as far as I can tell -- I'm actually starting to wonder if I need to recompile OpenCV for VS2015